# MacOs 10.12.6 : Error while installing Xapian : Operation Not permitted

Tags: installation, macos-sierra, xapian

I'm trying to install xapian from source on MACOS 10.12.6.
I am able to build the source but unable to install it ,

the error is :

```
/bin/sh ../libtool   --mode=install /usr/bin/install -c   xapian.la 
'/usr/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20131226'
libtool: install: /usr/bin/install -c .libs/xapian.so 
/usr/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20131226/xapian.so
install: /usr/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20131226/xapian.so: 
Operation not permitted
make[5]: *** [install-phpextLTLIBRARIES] Error 71
make[4]: *** [install-am] Error 2
```

I followed these steps in the xapian directory :

```
./bootstrap
./configure --without-perl --without-tcl --prefix='/usr/local'
make
sudo make install
```

Would be great if anyone could suggest how to resolve this error .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Recent macOS versions come with something called "System Integrity Protection" (or SIP), which prevents you (even as root) from installing files in certain places on the operating system. You have three main options:

1. [Turn off SIP](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/208478/how-do-i-disable-system-integrity-protection-sip-aka-rootless-on-macos-os-x) (this is pretty drastic, and most people won't want to do that).
2. Install the PHP extension to a custom location: `sudo make install PHP_EXTENSION_DIR=$HOME/php-local`. You'll then need to set PHP's `extension_dir` to find it, something like `php -d extension_dir=$HOME/php-local -r 'require_once("xapian.php");'`. In this case, you probably want to set `PHP_EXTENSION_DIR` to something like `/usr/local/lib/php/extensions`.
3. Install PHP from [homebrew](https://brew.sh/): `brew tap homebrew/homebrew-php` and build the Xapian bindings against that (this may involve more effort).

Of course, if you don't need PHP bindings, you can disable building them in the same way you're disabling Perl and TCL bindings (which have the same problem on macOS): `./configure --without-perl --without-tcl --without-php --prefix=/usr/local`.

Comment: i tried without-php and then tried installing xapian with make and make install , but still when i include xapian.h in any c++ code i am getting error fatal xapian.h file not found

Comment: That is a different error. I suggest you use the mailing list for this, or IRC, and pastebin a complete log of your compile command and the error message you're seeing.